# How to configure ssl for Staging/Production in .Net Core 2.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.1

I am building an mvc web app using .NET Core 2.1. In the documentation on .net core under ListenOptions.UseHttps it states it will configure Kestrel with the default certificate ([doc found here](https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/blob/master/aspnetcore/fundamentals/servers/kestrel.md)).

Where does Kestrel look for this default certificate? How can I replace it for staging (where I would want to use one of our demo site certificates)? And for production (where I have a different cert again)?

My Program.cs content now looks like:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args); //This sets up Kestrel and adds appsettings.json to the configuration
        builder.UseStartup<Startup>();
        builder.ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, configurationBuilder) =>
        {
            var env = context.HostingEnvironment;
            configurationBuilder.SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath);
        });

        var host = builder.Build();
        host.Run();
    }
}
```

My Startup.cs Configure method

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        app.UseHsts();
    }
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseMvc(ConfigureRoutes);
}
```

The application runs fine with https on localhost. I am looking for a way to solve this via configuration (e.g. appSettings.{env}.json?) and not via custom  methods such as [this one](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/11/29/configuring-https-in-asp-net-core-across-different-platforms/)

Comment: We're using kestrel behind nginx and let nginx terminate ssl connections. But I think the following article describes the setup https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/11/29/configuring-https-in-asp-net-core-across-different-platforms/

Comment: Yes that is the one I referenced in my question as well towards the end. However, I would like to be able to configure Kestrel itself. Is your approach the recommended one for applications like these?

Comment: I think that has changed a little, but for a long time kestrel was not intended to directly serve to the outside. The docs still focus on hosting behind nginx/apache/… so I assume it is still the most common setup. We're using https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy (with docker) what provides us an easy way to get letsencrypt certs for all of our asp.net core apps.

Comment: May be this article will help you? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x

Comment: Looks promising, will give that approach a go.

Comment: Kestrel still isn't recommended to be used directly. It gets the job done, but it's not a true full-fledged web server, and lacks alot of features and controls you'll likely need.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The documentation mentioned by [xneg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3110970/xneg) helped solve this: [Kestrel web server implementation in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x)

Managed to get it to work by modifying the appsettings.DockerDevelopment.json file as follows:

```
{
  "Kestrel": {
    "EndPoints": {
      "HttpsDefaultCert": {
        "Url": "https://*:443"
      },
      "Http": {
        "Url": "http://*:80"
      }
    },
    "Certificates": {
      "Default": {
        "Path": "certifcate.pfx",
        "Password": "*********"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Kestrel is now able to run my app using https in a Docker container and on the staging server.